# MMVM Light NavigationService vs NavigationHelper in Universal App

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on how best handle the navigation service in a universal app as I'm confused on how to handle this.

If I create a blank application and just use a basic NavigationService as suggested in tutorial for mvvmlight and universal app, it doesn't handle the windows phone hardware back key and when I click it, it just closes the wp8.1 app.

I found an [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21021cbc-1fb3-476a-9c26-eb4fa1d97bea/how-to-handle-backkeypress-button-in-portable-for-universal-apps-?forum=wpdevelop) that suggest to add the HardwareButtons.BackPressed to the app.cs, but I don't like the idea to be honest. Maybe it's ok? Let me know.

The basic IHavigationService is registered in the `SimpleIoc`and is injected in via the constructor but as mentioned, this does not handle the back key for wp8 apps.

When I create a universal hub app, it doesn't use mvvmlight and it creates a navigationHelper class which contains the necessary code to handle both windows and wp apps but every time it is used, the declaration is done in the code behind of the relevant page rather than in the ViewModel.

Any suggestions on how best handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the best of both world:

In App.xaml.cs, you subscribe to HardwareButtons.BackPressed event:

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Create NavigationService class:

```
public static class NavigationService
    {
        public static Dictionary<Pages, Type> PageDictionary = new Dictionary<Pages, Type>();
        public static Frame MainFrame;
        public static void Configure(Frame frame)
        {
            PageDictionary.Add(Pages.MainPage, typeof(MainPage));
            PageDictionary.Add(Pages.Setting, typeof(SettingPage));

            MainFrame = frame;
        }

        internal static void GoBack()
        {
            if (MainFrame.CanGoBack)
                MainFrame.GoBack();
        }

        internal static bool CanGoBack
        {
            get
            {

                return MainFrame.CanGoBack;
            }
        }

        internal static void NavigateTo(Pages page, object parameter)
        {
            MainFrame.Navigate(PageDictionary[page], parameter);

        }
}
```

Pages  is an enum

In App.xaml.cs, after you initiate rootFrame, config the navigation service:

```
NavigationService.Configure(rootFrame);
```